# Trying to rotate multiple objects together and then move one, but rotation gets doubled

Tags: animation, parent

I'm familiar with Blender but I'm just now learning animation, and I thought a simple robot would be a good way to learn basics before I moved onto bones and such. The gif shows my problem: The cube is the parent of all the other parts, and I was trying to rotate the whole thing 30° and then have the bottom "jaw" slide down. I have the rotate bit down fine, but when I hit G to move the jaw, the jaw rotates an additional 30°.

I have noticed that the cube rotates from 0,0,0 to 0,0,-30 and the ladle stays at 0,0,0 through the whole rotation until I hit G, at which point it changes to 0,0,-30 (0,0,-60 relative to its starting point). I have tried Parent > Object (with and without Keep Transform), I've tried keyframing Child Of object constraints (though I may have done that wrong), and I have googled everything I can think of but have come up empty. This seems like it should be very simple to do, am I expecting too much or am I a dumbass? What is the best way to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: don't they have the same action?

Comment: Please upload your file

Comment: [Google Drive link to the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1udXXl1HBlyHuJ0tlEuheD9z8bhIlg8Rv)

Comment: It's the Rigid Body that creates this, do you have any good reason to make your objects Rigid Body?

Comment: @moonboots There was when I started this exercise because I wanted the jaw to flop around a little bit with physics, but I gave that up. Just switched it off and it works perfectly, exactly how I expected it should. Thank you so much!